# Accessing new Laravel config files during request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a scenario where Laravel config files are created and accessed during the same incoming request. However, when accessing the new stored config file's values, `config()` is unable to access the file's keys/values.

Here is an example scenario:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $settings = ['foo' => 'bar'];
    // Store the config.
    Storage::disk('config')->put("settings.php", '<?php return ' . var_export($settings, true) . ';');
    // Results in an error, value not found.
    $config_value = config('settings.foo'); 
}
```

Is there a way to re-register Laravel config files during a runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving contents to the php file `config/settings.php` is (obviously) not the best way to do it.

Either save the config to a database, or simply use the `config()` helper to assign the values like this:

```php
class MyConfigProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {
        $this->app->booted(function () {
            // This will set the config setting `config/settings.php['app_name']` at runtime:
            config([
                'settings.app_name' => 'My App Name'
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, make sure to load this service provider **as early in the stack as possible** in your `config/app.php['providers']` array. Basically it overwrites any predefined config that you have set in `config/settings.php`. You can even retrieve values here from the request object or your database.

Comment: could you please elaborate why directly saving config files is not considered a good way to solve this issue? Is `var_export()` not to be trusted?

Comment: I think it can be compared to `eval` since youre basically writing to a `.php` file which later gets executed. Youre also changing source files which means that if youre using a Git repo, it will continuously generate a change for that file.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the settings logic to retrieve settings from database and implemented your service provider workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a method for that:

```
config()->set('settings.foo', $somethingNew);
```

and then you can read it normally with:

```
$config_value = config('settings.foo');
```